# AudioKit: Crossfade 2 AKPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I want to cross fade 2 AKPlayer. For that i set the following fade to each player:

```
    let fade = AKPlayer.Fade()
    fade.inRampType = AKSettings.RampType.linear
    fade.inStartGain = 0
    fade.inTime = Double(fadeTime)
    fade.outRampType = AKSettings.RampType.linear
    fade.outStartGain = 1
    fade.outTime = Double(fadeTime)
```

Then i want to start the first player and schedule the second player to start right before the first player starts fading out:

```
firstPlayer.play(when: 0, hostTime: hostTime)
secondPlayer.play(when: 40, hostTime: hostTime)
```

But both players start immediately.

How can i archive that the second player starts with the exact delay?